# Advanced logical operations in MongoDB with Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, operator-keyword

I have a little problem with MongoDB, I'm trying to create a query with multiple operators with the Java driver. I'm looking for something like this : 
x1 : y1 OR (x2 : y2 AND x3 : y3)

At the moment I have this :

```
 BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();

 List<BasicDBObject> obj2 = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
 obj2.add(new BasicDBObject("x1", "y1"));
 andQuery.put("$or", obj2);

 List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
 obj.add(new BasicDBObject("x2", "y2"));
 obj.add(new BasicDBObject("x3", "y3"));
 andQuery.put("$and", obj);
```

And that give me this when I make a print :

```
 { "$or" : [ { "x1" : "x1"}] , "$and" : [ { "x2" : "x2"} , { "x3" : "y3"}]}
```

So I think the problem comes from the first ']' which should be at the end, so the $and will be in the $or array.

But how can I make this possible ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
BasicDBObject orQuery = new BasicDBObject();

List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("x2", "y2"));
obj.add(new BasicDBObject("x3", "y3"));
andQuery.put("$and", obj);

List<BasicDBObject> obj2 = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
obj2.add(new BasicDBObject("x1", "y1"));
obj2.add(andQuery);
orQuery.put("$or", obj2);
```

Comment: Perfect, I should have seen it before, I was trying to add the list instead of the query.. It gives me : { "$or" : [ { "x1" : "y1"} , { "$and" : [ { "x2" : "y2"} , { "x3" : "y3"}]}]} which is what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Comment: You are welcome! If everything is ok for you now don't forget to validate this answer so it will be marked as valid and close the subject